# Web API custom formatter for POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have one web application. In it, each user can have it's own localized culture set for his session. So, one user can have US culture, while the other can have e.g. UK culture, and so on...

The form is posted as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I have one Web API post method which is receiving my entity object as parameter. When I look at the entity, it has all the properties from form populated, which is as expected. Well, almost all...

In my entity I have property of type decimal. When I post value from form it is formatted and thus posted in localized format (e.g. "1.234,56"). Because of this, my model state is invalid and value for decimal property is not bound in my entity.

I want to overcome this on server side, setting custom JSON formatter for only that property of type decimal. Is it even possible to do so?

I have tried to create custom formatter, but it doesn't do anything. I know this is possible to achieve in MVC, but I can't believe that the same thing can't be done with Web API.

Comment: `When I post value from form it is formatted and thus posted in localized format (e.g. "1.234,56")`: is the form POSTed in JSON? Because `1.234,56` is not a valid value for a JSON property. Is this a string or something? Could you show a sample HTTP request to your Web API endpoint and more specifically the body?

Comment: Yes, it's in JSON. In model it is decimal, as I stated.

Comment: So it is sent as a string in the JSON payload, right? For example like this: `{"someDecimalProperty":"1.234,56"}` (because this is invalid JSON: `{"someDecimalProperty":1.234,56}`)? And you expect to bind this to a `decimal` property on your view model?

Comment: Exactly. Only, I don't expect this to bind out of box. I'm looking for a way to implement it.

Comment: I was wrong, it's not posted as JSON string but as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: ohhhh, this is very different. I have just posted an answer on how to do that with JSON. Deleting it...

Comment: Sorry for confusion, my mistake.